# Azure ARM deployment of a keyVault with multiple accessPolicies in a copy-block

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to deploy an Azure KeyVault with multiple `accessPolicies` based on `objectIds` in an array. I want to use the copy block, as there might be some more Ids added in future and I do not want to copy the entire block multiple times in the template but pass them as a list of params.

I cannot add the copy-block of accessPolicies inside the `KeyVault/vaults` ressource as it would expect multiple keyVaults and not multiple accessPolicies. That's why I put the `KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies` as a top-level resource with its own copy-block - following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/child-resource-name-type#outside-parent-resource).

However, now I have the problem of naming the `accessPolicies`-block: according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vault-create-template?tabs=CLI#add-an-access-policy-to-a-key-vault-resource-manager-template) I need to name the `accessPolicies`-block after the parent-keyVault-resource with the extension `/add` - but ARM also complains that I `cannot have multiple resources with the same name`.

I tried changing the name of the `accessPolicies`-block to:

- `concat('/add/', copyIndex())` -> Error: `incorrect segment length`
- `concat('/add', copyIndex())` -> Error: `Provided concat params invalid. Either all or none of the parameters must be an array`

I'm running out of ideas of how I can use the copy block in combination with the `accessPolicies` as a top-level resource. Any ideas how to solve this?

The JSON:

```
"parameters":{
  "objectIdList": {
     "type": "array"
   }
},

"variables": {
   "keyVaultName" : "[....]"
},

"resources": [
  {
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
  "name": "[variables('keyVaultName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
  "properties": {
    "sku": {
      "family": "A",
      "name": "standard"
    },
    "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
    "enableRbacAuthorization": false,
    "accessPolicies": [
    ],
    "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
    "networkAcls": {
      "defaultAction": "Allow",
      "bypass": "AzureServices"
    }
  },


  {
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
  "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
  "name": "[concat(variables('keyVaultName'), '/add')]",
  "properties": {
    "accessPolicies": [
      {
        "objectId": "[parameters('objectIdList')[copyIndex()]]",
        "permissions": {
          "certificates": [ "all" ],
          "keys": [ "all" ],
          "secrets": [ "all" ],
          "storage": [ "all" ]
        },
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]"
      }
    ]
  },
  "copy": {
    "name": "accessPolicies",
    "count": "[length(parameters('objectIdList'))]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[variables('keyVaultName')]"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution literally 15 minutes later... there is another syntax of the `copy`-block which can be used here.

I only have to `/add` one top-level `accessPolicies` resource with multiple policies inside and use a copy-block with `accessPolicies` as a name inside the `properties` block to iterate over my array.

JSON solution:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
  "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
  "name": "[concat(variables('keyVaultName'), '/add')]",
  "properties": {
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "accessPolicies",
        "count": "[length(parameters('objectIdList'))]",
        "input": {
          "objectId": "[parameters('objectIdList')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')]]",
          "permissions": {
            "certificates": [ "all", "purge" ],
            "keys": [ "all", "purge" ],
            "secrets": [ "all", "purge" ],
            "storage": [ "all" ]
          },
          "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[variables('keyVaultName')]"
  ]
}
```